Message: no such element: Unable to locate element exception - Python selenium
I am trying to find an element to click.  I am able to find the element using DevTools from a browser but using  Selenium I hit an error element not found.
My code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get("https://www.fsmone.com.my/funds/tools/factsheet/aham-bond-fund?fund=MYAFCAPF")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div\[@id='content'\]")))

element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span\[text()='Latest NAV Price '\]")
element.click()

It return the below error
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='Latest NAV Price ']"}

The source code


See the working refactored code below:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.fsmone.com.my/funds/tools/factsheet/aham-bond-fund?fund=MYAFCAPF")

# Create explicit wait object with wait time of 10s
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Latest NAV Price ']")))
element.click()
time.sleep(10)

Few points to note:

It is not best practice to mix implicit wait and explicit wait. If you notice I have removed driver.implicitly_wait(2) from your code. Just use one wait object to effectively locate all elements as I have done in above code.
You don't need to apply waits and check for any presence of element to click on your desired element(Latest NAV Price). I have removed the line of code where you are checking for presence of //div[@id='content']. Following code has already taken care of that

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Latest NAV Price ']")))


Without the source code you are working with its hard to say, but from here it looks like you are trying to just click text, not a button.
Using the stackoverflow upvote as an example,

this code should work for pressing the upvote xpath.
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="question"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/button[1]').click()

Are you trying to click a button/link or are you trying to select text from the page?

I am trying to click it.

The problem is because my browser is in fullscreen when I am using devtools. When using Selenium script, the browser is default to half my screen.
This site uses desktop mode code for fullscreen and mobile mode code for half screen.
